# Creating a $(angular).ready() for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery function that I want to run only after my AngularJS template has rendered on the page.

I know there's `$(document).ready()` for jQuery which runs the code inside it when the DOM is ready for JavaScript to run. But is it possible to create something like an `$(angular).ready()` that tells jQuery when Angular's template has loaded? Is there some easy way to get these two frameworks to talk to each other?

Comment: Have you checked out the solutions posted in these questions: [AngularJS: callback after render (work with DOM after render)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953348/angularjs-callback-after-render-work-with-dom-after-render) and [is there a post render callback for Angular JS directive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive).

Comment: have a look at viewcontentloaded event in angular

Comment: why not use `$(window).load` instead of document?